# How to make a fault tolerant Tarantool cluster

Tags: failover, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I have a cluster consisting of a master node and several replicas. I want, if the master or the hosting suddenly falls down, to have the possibility to perform a quick switchover and everything works again, what are the possible ways of making a failover in the Tarantool cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Tarantool Cartridge](https://www.tarantool.io/ru/doc/2.5/book/cartridge/topics/failover/) framework, it has several options available out-of-the-box.